# Remove class on collapse (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I tried looking for an answer, but none of it has solved my problem yet. I am a beginner in learning to understand this code language and I think that my problem lies there.

I have created a JSFiddle with what I have up until now.

(http://jsfiddle.net/fxmcb5yv/2/)!

This is my problem:

When the div expands, it adds the class 'selected', which does the following:

```
.selected {
    background-color: #70a6b7;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

This is all fine. But when I collapse it, I want .selected to be removed. I have tried several things with removeClass and such, but all of them did not do anything or cause even more problems.

I was wondering if any of you could help me fix this problem.

This is what I tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".desc_div").slideUp();
$(".open_div").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected").next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow").siblings('.desc_div').slideUp().removeClass("selected").end();
  });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the code you tried which did not work.

Comment: Can you please tell us what the exact behavior you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.toggleClass()` instead of `.addClass()` for toggling classname:

```
$(".open_div").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("selected").next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow").siblings('.desc_div').slideUp().removeClass("selected").end();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2w6f1r2f/)**

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I wanted to thank you for your help! It turned out to be a little more complicated because in my code the four divs aren't in one main div, but 2 vs 2 if you get what I mean.

So that's why toggleClass caused problems for me. I don't know how to explain it, but eventually someone came up with a total different solution which seemed to work (until another problem occured).

Anyway, thank you!